# Javascript value comparison is illogical

Tags: javascript, html, css

First the code:

```
function focusAction(thefield, autofill) {

if (thefield.value == thefield.defaultValue && (thefield.style.color == 'rgb(153, 153, 153)' || thefield.style.color == '#999999')) {
    thefield.style.color = "#000000";
    if (autofill == "")
    thefield.value = '';
}
}

function blurAction(thefield, autofill) {
    //var content = thefield.value;
if (thefield.value == '' || thefield.value == null) {
    thefield.value = thefield.defaultValue;
    if (autofill == "")
        thefield.style.color = "#999999";
} else {
    //thefield.style.color="green";
}
}
```

So here is the deal: If I put if (thefield.value == " " || thefield.value == null) it works but you must have a space. If the box is empty it does not work. This only affects textareas. It works fine with blank textboxes.

I am really baffled by it, anyone have any idea on why a space works but an empty "" or '' or null doesn't?

Comment: as usual - it's not the problem with javascript - it's a problem with your code. probably outside part posted in question

Comment: you should use jsfiddle.net to show an example, also you might want to try the `.text` instead of value.

Comment: That's because your TEXTAREA element probably contains some white space characters. I recommend this: `if ( thefield.value.trim() === '' )` (Note that `trim()` is not implemented in IE8, so you would have to take care of that manually.)

Comment: If anyone runs across this, I had some other javascript that was interfering with the style. BARELY found it. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

What doesn't work? This works with empty `''`: http://jsfiddle.net/wYPNX/

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestions:**

- **Use classes for visual changes.**  CSS is much easier to change than JavaScript, and is much more robust.
- **I recommend using a more robust form plug-in.**  If this is undesirable, that's fine.  I just suggest using plug-ins as there is more support and usually have less bugs than self created projects.
- **Trim your inputs.**  That means that leading and trailing spaces are disregarded, giving you a lot better idea of what's actually there.  This will likely fix your problem, unless it is due to the next point.
- **Did you mean to compare to an empty space?**  Usually you would want to know if it was empty or null, not if it has a space or null.
- **Use `===` to compare with null.**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its worth inverting your code and testing it like this:

```
if (thefield.value && thefield.value.length > 0) {
    //thefield.style.color="green";
} 
else {
    thefield.value = thefield.defaultValue;
    if (autofill == "")
        thefield.style.color = "#999999";
}
```